# Sort object by keys in ascending order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have an object like this

```
let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}
```

Is it possible to sort it by its keys in ascending order? The result I want to achieve would be:

```
obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "8": "961127",
    "9.5": "961115"
}
```

It would probably involve creating a new object which I don't mind, just not sure how to get this done

Comment: it is not possible, because the order is defined by index like keys (32 bit positive integer) are sorted first, then all other in insertation order and finally symbols.

Comment: Objects are unordered collections of properties, you cannot sort them.

Answer (score 5):

**You can't**. Object keys are not sortable and you can't predict how each browser will iterate through object.

**But you can use an array as index** like this.
Remember to format your keys. If it's a string, juste use `.sort()`.
Else you should probably compare your keys with `.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b));`

```js
let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}

let index = Object.keys(obj).sort()

// iterate method
index.forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key, obj[key])
})

// or array of sorted object
let sortedArrayOfObject = index.map((v) => {
  return {key: v, value: obj[v]}
})
console.log(sortedArrayOfObject)
```

Comment: You'll want to [sort these numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007/1048572) using `.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.replace(/,/,'')) - parseFloat(b.replace(/,/,'')))` though

Comment: I think keys should be formated before. Because we don't know if keys are string or float (actually, we can see period and comma)

Comment: Yes, the input format is wonky and should be fixed, but still the string keys should not be compared lexically but as numbers.

Comment: Btw, regarding the `sortedArrayOfObject`, that format is horrible to work with. Much better would be `{key: v, value: obj[v]}` or `[v, obj[v]]`.

Comment: Indeed, I use mine like this too. updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var keySorted = Object.keys(obj).sort();
var newObj={}; 
for (let i = 0; i < keySorted.length; i++) {
    newObj[keySorted[i]]=obj[keySorted[i]];
}
obj=newObj;
```

Comment: Hi. This code contains errors and does not work as intended. Please revise or remove it if it cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}
const objSortedByKeys = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b)=>a[0].localeCompare(b[0])));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that you can do.

```js
let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}

let obj2 = {};

for (let key of Object.keys(obj).sort()) {
    console.log(key);
    obj2[key] = obj[key];
}

console.log(obj2);
```

But the problem is that you wanted to iterate them. So, an alternative is to sort the keys and iterate them:

```js
let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}

for (let key of Object.keys(obj).sort()) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
}
```

Or you could even use a generator:

```js
const myIterator = function* (obj) {
    let rawKeys = Object.keys(obj);
    let keys = rawKeys.sort();
    for (let key of keys) {
        yield key;
    }
}

let obj = {
    "5": "961131",
    "8": "961127",
    "5,5": "961107",
    "7": "961103",
    "9.5": "961115"
}

for (let key of myIterator(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
}
```